# View file via controller, not via direct access. htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

In my view I have a link that allow the user to view a file in a new window:

```
<li>
  <a href="/files/fileview/<?php echo $files_selectallrow->fileid; ?>" target="_blank">
    <i class=" icon-file-eye"></i>
    View this file
  </a>
</li>
```

This loads the file via the controller, which displays the file in a view:

Controller:

```
//Load model
$this->load->model('files/files_model');        

//Lookup file
$file = $this->files_model->findfilebyid($fileid);

//Get data      
$data['file'] = base_url(). '' . $file->filenamepath."/".$file->filename.".".$file->filetype ;
$data['header'] = $file->filetypeheader;

//Load view
$this->load->view('portal/files/fileview_view', $data);
```

View:

```
// Let the browser know what file is coming.
header("Content-type: ".$header);
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));

// Send the file to the browser.
readfile($file);
```

This works perfect, as it should. 
Now of course, by default, you could be able to view the file, by accessing it via the direct url, for instance: http://www.example.com/filestorage/myfile.pdf

I wanted to prevent this by adding a .htaccess file with a Deny from all rule.
However, this also blocks the view for viewing my file...

I am kind of lost how I should approach this. Should I keep the Deny from all .htaccess rule, and display my file another way, or, should I adapt the .htaccess file so it denies all, except from my view?

Thanks

Comment: With your approach you can have your pdfs outside of your public_html folder to prevent global access. Just make sure you upload them on a directory before public_html and you save the appropriate path correctly to your database.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're still accessing the file using its URL, your should use the actual filepath to read the file.

Normally that's instead of `base_url()` you'd use `'./'` which means it will start from the location where you put your index.php file.

And You don't need a view here, You should put that code in your controller; having a view here serves no purpose at all.